# How to know Sheet ID that using BigQuery Sheet Connector

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

Currently there is many user in my place that analyze BigQuery data with using feature [connected sheet](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/connected-sheets). For security reason, I wonder if i can get all spreadsheet ID that using my data from BigQuery. Is there any ways to do that?

In [this article](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9702507), it says that I can find spreadsheet ID in the audit log. But I can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1: You can pick the sheetId from the open google sheet

[image]

and query the cloud logging - you should be able to find docId as highlighted.

[image]

However, this is manual one sheet at a time, other option can be below -
to find all "connected sheets" - first step can be to query bigquery information schema - see below query, the job_id and labels give away the connected sheets queries run on BigQuery.

```
SELECT job_id, lbl.key,lbl.value,creation_time
FROM `region-australia-southeast1`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS, unnest(labels) as lbl
WHERE job_id like 'sheets_dataconnector_%'
order by creation_time desc --2023-07-12 10:22:26.558000 UTC
```

See screenshot:

[image]

Step 2: Use the JOB_IDs and enter in CLoud logging dashboard as above, this should give you all docIds

Hope this helps